# Key binding for changing font face

Tags: key-bindings, fonts

I want to be able to switch between "Consolas-12" and "Georgia-13" using key bindings. Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to set the default font as you might with the "Options -> Set default font..." menu item?

The relevant command is `set-frame-font`. You can write a command to toggle between two (or more) fonts like this:

```
(defcustom my-default-fonts
  '("Consolas-12" "Georgia-13") "List of default fonts")

(defun toggle-frame-font ()
  "Toggle between default fonts."
  (interactive)
  (add-to-list 'my-default-fonts (pop my-default-fonts) t) ; rotate list
  (set-frame-font (car my-default-fonts) nil t))
```

Then bind it to key, for example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>") #'toggle-frame-font)
```